# Is it legal to pack LibGdx libraries in my jar file? And to obfuscate them?

Tags: java, libgdx, encryption, deployment

I'm using LibGDX and deploying a runnable jar file, using the Eclipse feature, with libraries extracted into it. There are also .so files and .dlls inside.

1. Is it legal to do so? I didn't find anything about deploying to a single jar file.
2. If 1 is legal, if I obfuscate the jar file, maybe with [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/), will it be still legal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously not a lawyer, so this isn't legal advice, but my personal interpretation is:

The code is licensed under [Apache License, Version 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0). If you read the **Redistribution** section:

> You may reproduce and distribute copies of the Work or Derivative
>   Works thereof in any medium, with or without modifications, and in
>   Source or Object form...

So, yes, you can package it with your jar file. And I would argue that obfuscating the code is modifying it. However, one of the conditions of redistribution is:

> If the Work includes a "NOTICE" text file as part of its distribution, then any Derivative Works that You distribute must include a readable copy of the attribution notices contained within such NOTICE file...

You need to keep all the notices intact. So don't obfuscate those away :).

Comment: Chosen this answer because it was more accurate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Google Code page](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/), the license is attribution + share-alike. I quote (emphasis mine):

> Share Alike — If you **alter, transform,** or build upon this work, **you may distribute the resulting work** *only under the same or similar license* to this one.

That means "yes."

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer the answer above :)